# Updating success/error page for Smart Capture

Tags: marketing-cloud, microsites

I am building a smart capture form that sends an email via a Triggered Send. Upon submitting the form the default marketing cloud success page is displayed. How do I change this page? I updated the "success URL" within the smart capture content area, but that did not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this change by updating the HTML rather than the smart capture component of the content area.